# Magento - replicate behaviour of email template with variable in admin

Tags: magento

I want to have a functionality in Magento where i can add text field to the admin are and allow a user to add a code snippet which will have a placeholder for a variable in it.

At runtime I will grab the code snippet via getStoreConfig and replace the variable/placeholder with the value i need.

I have managed to do everything apart from how to add the variable and replace.

So i do not need help in creating the config in admin etc.

An example would be that the user entered in a config field the following:

```
<script>
  alert('{{amazing_value}}');
</script>
```

then in my template i would do:

```
$codeSnippet = Mage::getStoreConfig('path_to_config');
$amazingValue = "This will replace the variable";

// Something here :) (this bit im not sure about where the variable is translated)

echo $codeSnippet
```

The output from then be:

```
    <script>
      alert('This will replace the variable');
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your "Something here" area, you could try:

```
 $codeSnippet = str_replace("{{amazing_value}}",$amazingValue,$codeSnippet);
```